# JQGrid jquery-ui combobox в форме для редактирования. Содержит ли значение?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mvc, jquery-ui, jqgrid

Всем привет. Столкнулся со следующей проблемой:

На форме редактирования необходимо выбирать значения из выпадающих списков, при этом списки довольно большие(>8000 строк). Чтобы пользователь мог искать в комбобоксе нужные значения, я прикрутил jquery-ui-combobox. Однако при появлении этой формы, значения в них отсутствуют:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Без combobox-ui, в обычном DropDownList значения присутствуют/отображаются. И, к слову говоря, если отредактировать **только** поле `Минимальное количество`, **НЕ** появляется нижеприведенное сообщение и все проходит нормально, редактируется только оно, все остальное остается без изменений(значит значения где то есть?).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В остальном комбобоксы работают нормально: значения выбираются и таблица редактируется так как требуется.

Есть ли способ отобразить значения в комбобоксах после открытия формы?

Привожу кусок кода:

```js
$("#bmList").jqGrid({
        url: bmListUrl,
        editurl: NovMarketEditUrl,
        colNames: ['ID', 'Аптека', 'Аптека', "Груп. код", 'Наименование', 'Наименование', 'Минимальное количество'],
        datatype: "json",
        colModel: [
            { name: 'id', index: 'id', key: true, width: 5, editable: false, editoptions: { readonly: true, style: "width: 30px" } },
            { name: 'ca_id', index: 'ca_id', hidden: true, viewable: true, editable: true, stype: 'select', edittype: 'select', editrules: { required: true, edithidden: true, custom: true, custom_func: ddlSelected },
                editoptions: {
                    dataUrl: "/NovMarket/GetAptCode",
                    dataInit: function (elem) {
                        $(elem).combobox();
                    }
                }
            },
            { name: 'new_num', index: 'new_num', width: 20, editable: false },
            { name: 'gk_id', index: 'gk_id', width: 7, editable: false, sortable: true },
            {
                name: 'gk_id', index: 'gk_id', hidden: true, viewable: true, editable: true, stype: 'select', edittype: "select", editrules: { required: true, edithidden: true, custom: true, custom_func: ddlSelected },
                editoptions: {
                                dataUrl: "/NovMarket/GetGroupCode",
                                dataInit: function (elem) {
                                    $(elem).combobox();
                                }
                             }
            },
            { name: 'gk_name', index: 'gk_name', width: 80, editable: false },
            { name: 'MinQty', index: 'MinQty', width: 15, align: "right", editable: true, edittype: 'text', sortable: true },
        ],
        prmNames: { id: "id" },
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10, 20, 30],
        pager: '#bmPager',
        loadonce: false,
        sortname: 'id',
        viewrecords: true,
        sortorder: "desc",
        caption: "Новинки",
        width: 800,
        height: 300
    })
    .jqGrid('navGrid', '#bmPager', {
        edit: true, add: true, del: true,  view: false, search: false, refresh: true,
        width: 800,
        height: 800
    },
    {
        width: 600,
        recreateForm: false,
        closeAfterEdit: true
    },// edit options
    {
        width: 600,
        recreateForm: false,
        closeAfterAdd: true
    }, // add options
    { reloadAfterSubmit: true }, // del options
    { top: 100, left: 100, sopt: ['cn', 'bw', 'eq', 'ew'] }// search options
    )
    .jqGrid('navButtonAdd', '#bmPager', {
        caption: "",
        buttonicon: "ui-icon-custom-excel",
        onClickButton: function () {
            window.location = showReportUrl;
        },
        position: "last",
        title: "Выгрузить в Excel",
        cursor: "pointer"
    }
    
    )
```

Не могу разобраться самостоятельно с этой проблемой.
Пытался задать свое значение таким образом в разных событиях формы:

```js
..........
  $(elem).combobox();
  $(elem).combobox('setvalue', '10');
..........
```

Результата нет. При всем прочем если поместить этот список не на форму редактирования, а непосредственно на страницу и задать ей значение, то все проходит гладко. Но не на этой форме.

P.S. jqGrid 4.7.0, jquery-ui-1.12.0, jquery-3-1-0

Comment: я только-что написал [комментарий](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39698111/jqgrid-jquery-ui-combobox-in-editform-values-are-somewhere#comment66701914_39698111) к английской копии вопроса. Если будут проблемы с языком, то мне можно отвечать по-русски здесь.

Comment: кстати, я лично предпочитаю использовать [select2](https://select2.github.io/) в подобных случаях. См. [мой старый ответ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37876387/315935) и [этот](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/formEditOnDoubleClick-jqueryui-fa3.htm) пример использования.

Comment: @Oleg , Спасибо большое, разобрался с вашей помощью. Хотя странно почему в такой популярной версии jqGrid нет такой полезной функции как в вашем гриде...

Comment: Рад, что смог помочь. Мой fork - это и есть дальмейшее развитие jqGrid 4.7.0. Я старался сохранять максимум совместимости с jqGrid 4.7.0, устраняя баги, улучшая скорость и реализуя новые возможности. [Тут](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/compare/v4.7.0...master) можно видеть, что колличество коммитов после v4.7.0 превышает 1200. Так что, `selectFilled` - это лишь малый пример новых возможностей.  Например, я рекомендую использовать векторный иконки Font Awesome. См пример [здесь](http://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html#type_of_data_code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В jQuery UI 1.12.0 отсутствует стандартный combobox widget, который можно использовать как `$(elem).combobox();`. Вы использовали `dataUrl` а комбинайии с каким-то combobox-plugin'ом.

Я полагаю, что причина вашей проблемы в следующем: Вы вызаваете `combobox` на **пустом** `<select>`'е, **до получения** и обработки данных от `dataUrl`. Я рекоммендовал бы Вам перейти с jqGrid 4.7.0 на [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), которую я развиваю после смены лицензионного соглашения в версии 4.7.1, переименования продукта в Guriddo jgGrid JS (см. [здесь](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?p=1438) и [здесь](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334)).

Free jqGrid поддерживает новый коллбэк `selectFilled`, который можно использовать в `editoptions` вместо `dataInit`. Важно подчеркнуть, что `dataInit` вызывается сразу, в то время как `selectFilled` только посли одработки данных от `dataUrl`. Так что `<select>` уже заполнен данными и `$(elem).combobox();` должен работать.

Кстати, я лично предпочитаю использовать [select2](https://select2.github.io/) в подобных случаях. См. [мой старый ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37876387/315935) и [этот пример](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/formEditOnDoubleClick-jqueryui-fa3.htm) использования. Еще я бы рекомендовал Вам просмотреть новые возможности [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) которые я отисываз в readme к каждой публикуемей версии. [Вики](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki) и [предварительная версия документации](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html) могут дать дополнительную информацию.

Comment: _В jQuery UI 1.12.0 отсутствует стандартный combobox widget..._
Да, вы правы, не правильно выразился..я использовал [jquery-ui autocomplete combobox](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox), а под "обычным DropDownList" я имел ввиду - `<select id="countires" name="countires"><option value="">Countries</option>.......`